# Cardinality of Cauchy Sequences in Natural Numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Consider the set $S$ consisting of all cauchy sequences $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $ a_n \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n$. Is the set $S$ countable? Justify your Answer.

Attempt

Cauchy $\rightarrow$ Convergent.Let sequence $\{ a_n \}$ converge to $N$

Thus for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-N|$ for all $n>N_0$.         (DEFINITION 1)

Choose $\epsilon=0.001$
Because any two natural numbers differ by atleast $1$ We must have all $a_n=N$ for all $n>N_0$.

Define
$D_{K}=\{$Sequences where $N_0=K \}$  (REFER DEFINITION 1 for $N_0$

$S=D_1 \cup D_2....... \cup D_K......$

Further note that each set $D_K$ where $N_0=K$ has cardinality$ \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} ...... \times \mathbb{N} $

No. Of $\mathbb{N} $ is K+1.

Each set $D_K$ is countable because its product of finitely many $\mathbb{N} $.

Hence countable sum of countable set is countable hence S is countable.

Comment: What is definition 1?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Line 8...The statement starting from "THUS FOR ANY ......"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of this proof is very good. The proof itself is quite close to correct. The one point where I'd be more careful is the choice of $N_0$: as you've written it, the choice of $N_0$ is not unique. Perhaps try defining $D_K$ as the set of sequences for which $K$ is the *least* integer satisfying $|a_n-N|<0.001$ for all $n>K$

Comment: Okay Sir...Thanks